# Elasticsearch not using all storage drives

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 6-node `elasticsearch 5.5` cluster with their `path.data` set to the following:

```
path.data: "/data/0/elasticsearch,/data/1/elasticsearch,/data/2/elasticsearch,/data/3/elasticsearch,/data/4/elasticsearch"
```

I have restarted all the nodes after the config change however only 1 node in the cluster actually writes to `/data/0/elasticsearch` and `/data/1/elasticsearch`. All the other 5 nodes have only been writing to `/data/0/elasticsearch`

To give you more insight into my cluster settings:

For my index => `"number_of_shards":"5"`

How do I configure the cluster to write evenly across all drives `/data/0/` through `/data/4/` and across all nodes.

**Update 1:**
Here is my health check report.

```
{
    "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
    "status": "green",
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 6,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 6,
    "active_primary_shards": 6,
    "active_shards": 12,
    "relocating_shards": 0,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 0,
    "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
    "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
    "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
    "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
    "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100.0
}
```

Comment: can you do a health check on the shards? this might help https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html

Comment: @khuderm Please see my Update 1